# make list of object inside viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I got this viewModel:

```
public class BasicViewModel
    {
        public BasicLayoutPage BasicLayOutPage { get; set; }
        public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

How do i create a list of the Settings inside this viewmodel?

I can create a list of the whole class like this:

```
var t = new List<BasicViewModel>();
```

But I need to do this to the `Settings` inside...

Comment: Your ViewModel only has 1 Settings. No list needed/applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's most simple, you can do this:

```
public class BasicViewModel
{
    public BasicLayoutPage BasicLayOutPage { get; set; }
    public IList<Settings> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

I tend to create a constructor also, just to save hassle later on, which initialises any lists I use:

```
public BasicViewModel()
{
    this.Settings = new List<Settings>();
}
```

e.g.

```
var viewModel = new BasicViewModel();

viewModel.Settings.Add(new Settings());
```

but this is subjective, each to their own.